# Should I ignore the launchSettings.json file from being committed in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I find this relatively known GitHub repository, where they considered `launchSettings.json` file (which is used by Visual Studio 2017 for .Net Core projects) is to be **ignored**.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Why should it be ignored? I used always in the company I work in to commit it, I am curious to know if there is any reason to ignore it.

Comment: I am guessing because it could be more user specific settings.  For example you might use IIS to host the site while a coworkers uses IIS express

Comment: @KenTucker I though also about that, but now I think I found the actual answer.

Comment: `launchSettings.json` has actually been removed from this `.gitignore` - https://github.com/github/gitignore/commit/c26008c00dac481a1f780751d6d005d52fd15b83#diff-07fccc01505e9b231e926168fc909197

Answer (score 39):

`launchSettings.json` should *not* be ignored. That repository has since been updated to not ignore it: https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2705

> **Reasons for making this change:**
>
> Ignoring `launchSettings.json` does not make much sense. Now .NET CLI even considers this file when running with `dotnet run`, as you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore2x).
>
> This settings will be useful if shared among project members, so it should be commited to the repo.
>
> **Links to documentation supporting these rule changes:**
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask you to give a bit more information about this file? For example what kind of information or settings will be shared in it? Just to make the answer includes everything necessary.

Comment: More documentation about the `launchSettings.json` file can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#development
Since the original question was about ignoring it in version control, I'd suggest asking a new question for more detailed information about the contents of this file, rather than increasing the scope of this existing question.

Comment: If `launchSettings.json` is supposed to be in git, how can we control Environment setting (Development, Production, etc.) if I have it set in this file to 'Development'? Especially in the context of CI/CD.

Comment: Also local paths in start arguments... This does not look like a file that should be under version control at first glance.

Answer (score 26):

One reason that this might be done as a general practice is to keep secrets out of the repo.

If you're using environment variables to store DB passwords, API keys, and so on, you can configure those for your [dev hosting environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) under Project Properties -> Debug, as key-value pairs.

That configuration gets persisted locally in the project's `launchSettings.json`, so by keeping that file out of commits you avoid leaking privileged information into your repo.

Note though, that the current best practice is not to store secrets in this way at all during development, but to use the [Secrets Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets) instead.

Answer (score 4):

OK now I know why, I deleted that file, but the options of this project are still saved somewhere there, the options simply did not get lost after deleting this file. **The file seems to be automatically generated** when I do any new change to the project options, so my old version with the new changes is going to be there again.

I am not sure what is the benefit of it in this case, but at least I can say we can probably exclude it from the source control.

Please correct me if I missed anything.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context of your project,

If you are going to share your source code with your colleagues or client and wanted to run the project with the same set of settings which you have used apart from default like `"uriFormat"` which will redirect to a specific Url on application start.

This kind of settings will not be available to next user if it is going to run the code from your repository.