# How to keep Environment setting out of git repository

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables, development-environment

I'd like to be able to load different configs depending on the environment I'm running in (Development or Production). To do this, I followed the article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

The article instructed me to add the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` setting to `launchSettings.json` to run my application locally in the "Development" environment. Now, the problem is that `launchSettings.json` is also pushed to the GIT repository. It means that my code will always run in "Development" environment. What if I had some CI/CD pipeline connected to my repository? I guess it would deploy my app in "Development" instead of "Production", which is obviously wrong.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

We use Environment Variables on "the host" or docker container to overwrite a bunch of settings e.g. ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

We started with config filed on the host which would overwrite appsettings but this approach didn't scale well. Now we set the Environment Variables when we deploy the Application (for us the docker container).

If you are using "CreateDefaultBuilder" the environment variables will overwrite all settings other than the command line arguments as you can read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Ok, so how do you set the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" locally? With `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: Yes exactly the development settings are in the launchSettings.json

Comment: Ok, but the thing is, when you deploy your application, doesn’t launchSettings.json get deployed with it? Doesn’t it make your app ALWAYS work in Development?

Comment: I would guess that the launchSettings.json is used by your IDE to set the Environment Variables for your machine. So they won't be used by the app in your deployed environment. But make sure you set the appropriate environment variables on the deployed machine/container to not rely on the default values.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use something like [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) ?
Just create one at the git root directory and write `launchSettings.json` into it. 
Then run `git rm --cached`. After that the `launchSettings.json` file should no longer be commited by git.
I am not very familiar with git too so fell free to spot any mistake.

Comment: That was my first idea. However, as I see, `launchSetting.json` is actually supposed to be in the GIT repo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377058/should-i-ignore-launchsettings-json-file-from-being-committed-in-git

Comment: Sorry for not being helpful!